# iOS - Assigning variable to property of an object in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, variables, properties, cell

I have a SQL DB that contains shops with openings days / hours per day. I calculate the day of today and want to have the property value in a custom cell.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
int day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

switch (day) {
    case 1:
        openingsDag = @"open_ma"; 
        break;
    case 2:
        openingsDag = @"open_di";
        break;
    case 3:
        openingsDag = @"open_woe";
        break;
    case 4:
        openingsDag = @"open_do";
        break;
    case 5:
        openingsDag = @"open_vr";
        break;
    case 6:
        openingsDag = @"open_za";
        break;
    case 7:
        openingsDag = @"open_zo";
        break;
    default: 
        break;
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I assign the property values to the labels from a mutablearray:

```
cell.naamLabel.text = [[winkelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] naam];
cell.openingsLabel.text = [[winkelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] openingsDag];
```

This seems not to work, I have tried several other ways (stringWithFormat, cell.openingsLabel instead of cell.openingsLabel.text, ...) to get the data in the label but just can't seem to get it right.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging with NSLogs or step through the code.  Is winkelArray not nil?  Is naamLabel nil?  Does the naam property return anything?  If you hard-code a value (eg. `cell.naamLabel.text = @"hello";`), does it work?  Etc.

Comment: I did the first steps of debugging, the problem is at setting openingsLabel.text. [[winkelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] openingsDag] it thinks openingsDag is a property of a winkel so I tried it with stringWithFormat but it sets the value of the label to cell.openingsLabel.text = [[winkelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] openingsDag]; as a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method to calculate the day was correct but my return type wasn't...

```
-(NSString*)berekenOpeningdag:(Winkel*)w {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ee"];
int day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

NSString *openingsUrenReturn = @"";


switch (day) {
    case 1:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_ma;
        break;
    case 2:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_di;
        break;
    case 3:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_woe;
        break;
    case 4:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_do;
        break;
    case 5:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_vr;
        break;
    case 6:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_za;
        break;
    case 7:
        openingsUrenReturn = w.open_zo;
        break;
    default: 
        break;
}
return openingsUrenReturn;
```

And there, I answered my own question!

Answer (score 0):

Check your date format.  "dd" gives you the day of the **month**.  Looking at your switch statement, you are expecting the day of the **week**.  The date format string for that would be "ee".

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it! But thats not really the problem at this point. I set the variable 'openingsDag' to a string which resembles a property of a shop.
The problem is with setting the label.text with the variable: cell.openingsLabel.text = [[winkelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] openingsDag];